# Bus Error only when running on Solarix Unix Box

Tags: c, unix, sun, sparc, bus-error

It compiles up and runs on my Linux box(Ubuntu) as well as other linux boxes both x86 and x64 but on a SunOS Generic_142900-02 sun4u sparc unix box, it crashes on the line

```
matrix->col_head[i] = col_h;
```

with a bus error, Also, when i compile it up with GCC -G, GDB fails to find any debuging symbols

Here is the Code:

```
typedef unsigned short short_u;
typedef struct node{
  short_u         row;
  short_u         col;
  int             value;
  struct node*    row_l;
  struct node*    col_l;
}node_t;

typedef struct matrix{
  short_u     N;
  node_t**    row_head;
  node_t**    col_head;
}matrix_t;

matrix_t* init_matrix(int N){
  matrix_t* matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t*));
  matrix->row_head = malloc(sizeof(node_t*)*N);
  matrix->col_head = malloc(sizeof(node_t*)*N);
  matrix->N = N;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      /* row */
      node_t* row_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
      row_h->col = 0;
      row_h->row = i+1;
      row_h->value = 0;
      row_h->col_l = row_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->row_head[i-1]->row_l = row_h;
      matrix->row_head[i] = row_h;
      /* col */
      node_t* col_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
      col_h->col = i+1;
      col_h->row = 0;
      col_h->value = 0;
      col_h->row_l = col_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->col_head[i-1]->col_l = col_h;
      matrix->col_head[i] = col_h;
  }
  matrix->row_head[N-1]->row_l = matrix->row_head[0];
  matrix->col_head[N-1]->col_l = matrix->col_head[0];

  return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
matrix_t* matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t*));
```

you allocate space of a pointer to a `matrix_t`, which is not enough for the entire `matrix_t`. Your bus error is probably the result of accessing unallocated memory at `matrix->row_head` and `matrix->col_head`.

You repeat this mistake in lines

```
  node_t* row_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
```

and

```
  node_t* col_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
```

The fact that you don't get a segfault on the Linux machines is a happy accident.

Comment: But i allocate row_head and col_head in the next 2 lines, and since matrix_t* is only the pointer, shouldn't that be enough? or should i sizeof(matrix_t)

Comment: matrix_t * is a pointer, but you're not allocating space for a pointer. sizeof(matrix_t) would be correct, yes.

Comment: i think it's strange that the above code worked for matrixes as large ass 1000*1000 and produced valid result on a linux box.

Comment: The Linux box was probably rounding the allocation up to 16 bytes (or possibly more) which was enough for a full `matrix_t` and `node_t`.  Your `matrix_t` structure is a fixed size, and it doesn't matter how large you make it (1000x1000 or 1x1).

Comment: A Bus error is not from unallocated memory, it is an Unaligned memory access, which an Ultrasparc is incapable of, though an X86 doesn't care. The wrong allocation is probably causing the memory to be not properly aligned, hence you can bullet test under Linux, but on a Sparc it will crash every time

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not run cleanly under `valgrind` on Mac OS X.

I wrapped it into a complete program thus:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short short_u;
typedef struct node{
  short_u         row;
  short_u         col;
  int             value;
  struct node*    row_l;
  struct node*    col_l;
}node_t;

typedef struct matrix{
  short_u     N;
  node_t**    row_head;
  node_t**    col_head;
}matrix_t;

static matrix_t* init_matrix(int N){
  matrix_t* matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix_t*));
  matrix->row_head = malloc(sizeof(node_t*)*N);
  matrix->col_head = malloc(sizeof(node_t*)*N);
  matrix->N = N;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      /* row */
      node_t* row_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
      row_h->col = 0;
      row_h->row = i+1;
      row_h->value = 0;
      row_h->col_l = row_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->row_head[i-1]->row_l = row_h;
      matrix->row_head[i] = row_h;
      /* col */
      node_t* col_h = malloc(sizeof(node_t*));
      col_h->col = i+1;
      col_h->row = 0;
      col_h->value = 0;
      col_h->row_l = col_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->col_head[i-1]->col_l = col_h;
      matrix->col_head[i] = col_h;
  }
  matrix->row_head[N-1]->row_l = matrix->row_head[0];
  matrix->col_head[N-1]->col_l = matrix->col_head[0];

  return matrix;
}

#if 0
static void free_matrix(matrix_t *matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->N; i++)
    {
        free(matrix->row_head[i]);
        free(matrix->col_head[i]);
    }
    free(matrix->row_head);
    free(matrix->col_head);
    free(matrix);
}
#endif /* 0 */

int main(void)
{
    matrix_t *m = init_matrix(100);
    //free_matrix(m);
    return(0);
}
```

It compiles cleanly.  It runs without actually crashing on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

#### Output from `valgrind`

However, `valgrind` complains like this (I called the program `xx`, and the source was `xx.c`):

```
==73807== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==73807== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==73807== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==73807== Command: ./xx
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000D11: init_matrix (xx.c:21)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000D2F: init_matrix (xx.c:22)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005130 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000D8A: init_matrix (xx.c:30)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005840 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000D5A: init_matrix (xx.c:26)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000DB7: init_matrix (xx.c:33)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E0A: init_matrix (xx.c:39)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005888 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000DDA: init_matrix (xx.c:35)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E37: init_matrix (xx.c:42)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005130 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000D9A: init_matrix (xx.c:32)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000DAF: init_matrix (xx.c:32)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005838 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000D5A: init_matrix (xx.c:26)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E1A: init_matrix (xx.c:41)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005130 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E2F: init_matrix (xx.c:41)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005890 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000DDA: init_matrix (xx.c:35)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E64: init_matrix (xx.c:44)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E79: init_matrix (xx.c:44)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E80: init_matrix (xx.c:44)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100009618 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000D5A: init_matrix (xx.c:26)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E88: init_matrix (xx.c:45)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005130 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid read of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000E9D: init_matrix (xx.c:45)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100005130 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000CF2: init_matrix (xx.c:20)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== Invalid write of size 8
==73807==    at 0x100000EA4: init_matrix (xx.c:45)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807==  Address 0x100009670 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==73807==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==73807==    by 0x100000DDA: init_matrix (xx.c:35)
==73807==    by 0x100000EE3: main (xx.c:66)
==73807== 
==73807== 
==73807== HEAP SUMMARY:
==73807==     in use at exit: 5,303 bytes in 235 blocks
==73807==   total heap usage: 235 allocs, 0 frees, 5,303 bytes allocated
==73807== 
==73807== LEAK SUMMARY:
==73807==    definitely lost: 1,608 bytes in 3 blocks
==73807==    indirectly lost: 1,600 bytes in 200 blocks
==73807==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73807==    still reachable: 2,095 bytes in 32 blocks
==73807==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73807== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==73807== 
==73807== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==73807== ERROR SUMMARY: 804 errors from 16 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

When I enabled the `free_matrix()` function, I got a few more errors, but I believe they were consequences of the problems in `init_matrix()`.  I then didn't get any leaked memory (the 'still reachable' memory is in the system libraries; all runs of `valgrind` have a noticeable amount of such memory on Mac OS X).

#### Amended Code

The diagnosis by [George Skoptsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257977/george-skoptsov) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159138/bus-error-only-when-running-on-solarix-unix-box/10159187#10159187) is spot-on.  This fixed code, with the `free_matrix()` enabled, works without error under `valgrind`.  Note the use of the idioms:

```
SomeType *variable = malloc(sizeof(*variable));
SomeType *arrayvar = malloc(sizeof(*arrayvar) * N);
```

Although a little uncomfortable at first, these avoid the problem you ran into.  I'm trying to remember to use them; I'm still relearning the techniques first learned long enough ago that I'm suffering from a dose of "it is hard to teach old dogs new tricks".

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short short_u;
typedef struct node{
  short_u         row;
  short_u         col;
  int             value;
  struct node*    row_l;
  struct node*    col_l;
}node_t;

typedef struct matrix{
  short_u     N;
  node_t**    row_head;
  node_t**    col_head;
}matrix_t;

static matrix_t* init_matrix(int N){
  matrix_t* matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix));
  matrix->row_head = malloc(sizeof(*matrix->row_head)*N);
  matrix->col_head = malloc(sizeof(*matrix->col_head)*N);
  matrix->N = N;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      /* row */
      node_t* row_h = malloc(sizeof(*row_h));
      row_h->col = 0;
      row_h->row = i+1;
      row_h->value = 0;
      row_h->col_l = row_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->row_head[i-1]->row_l = row_h;
      matrix->row_head[i] = row_h;
      /* col */
      node_t* col_h = malloc(sizeof(*col_h));
      col_h->col = i+1;
      col_h->row = 0;
      col_h->value = 0;
      col_h->row_l = col_h;
      if (i != 0)
          matrix->col_head[i-1]->col_l = col_h;
      matrix->col_head[i] = col_h;
  }
  matrix->row_head[N-1]->row_l = matrix->row_head[0];
  matrix->col_head[N-1]->col_l = matrix->col_head[0];

  return matrix;
}

static void free_matrix(matrix_t *matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->N; i++)
    {
        free(matrix->row_head[i]);
        free(matrix->col_head[i]);
    }
    free(matrix->row_head);
    free(matrix->col_head);
    free(matrix);
}

int main(void)
{
    matrix_t *m = init_matrix(100);
    free_matrix(m);
    return(0);
}
```

There are five places where `malloc()` is called; there are also five places where `free()` is called.  And two of the five allocations and frees are in 0..N-1 loops, which all balances nicely.

#### Revised output from `valgrind`

```
==73943== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==73943== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==73943== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==73943== Command: ./xx
==73943== 
==73943== 
==73943== HEAP SUMMARY:
==73943==     in use at exit: 2,095 bytes in 32 blocks
==73943==   total heap usage: 235 allocs, 203 frees, 8,519 bytes allocated
==73943== 
==73943== LEAK SUMMARY:
==73943==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73943==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73943==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73943==    still reachable: 2,095 bytes in 32 blocks
==73943==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==73943== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==73943== 
==73943== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==73943== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

### Lessons to learn

So, there are various lessons to learn from this brief story:

1. Be grateful the Sun pointed out the problem to you.
2. Learn how to use `valgrind`.
3. Consider using the `Type *pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));` idiom for allocations.

Comment: +1 for the idiom/pattern for ensuring your malloc is asking for enough memory.  Definitely something to get into the habit of.  Wouldn't it be great if the compiler could warn you of, "return value of malloc assigned to a pointer to a type larger than the requested memory allocation.".